# shp2pgsql Load Data Type Inconsistent

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, shp2pgsql

I'm having trouble when trying to upload a shape file in postgresql/PostGIS.
There's a field with type "date", but actually there'r two elements with content : '20012060' and it returns ERROR when I start shp2pgsql.
Is there any way to change all fields from dbf to character varying, using shp2pgsql or any other extension from PostGIS?

[image]

Comment: What does `SHOW DATESTYLE;` in Postgres tell you? My guess is that you will need to set your datestyle on the input table to YMD, ie, `SET datestyle = "ISO, YMD"`;

Comment: Actually, looking more closely, 20012060 is clearly not a date in any format. So, to answer your original question, one of the switches to shp2pgsql is -a, which means, append. So, you can create the table with the problem columns defined as varchar and then run shp2pgsql -a .....

Answer (score 2):

Is using ogr2ogr an option? If so you should be able to use `COLUMN_TYPES` option, see the [help section for PostgreSQL driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html).

Example of importing shape to postgis with the integer field "id" imported as text

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost user=postgres dbname=testdb password=somepassword" "/home/bera/GIS/data/test/polys.shp" -lco COLUMN_TYPES="id=text"
```

[image]

Data type of columns not specified seem to be set automatically, for example the "sometext" column.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the original question,  as valid an approach as it may be.